# Unable to upgrade the firmware of a Micro Bit

Tags: firmware, bbc-microbit

I have a Micro bit v1. Days before, I was unable to search the Bluetooth signal of it, so I followed the instruction on [microbit.org](https://microbit.org/get-started/user-guide/firmware/) to upgrade its firmware. But after I copied the firmware file into it, a `FAIL.TXT` file showed up in the disk `MAINTENANCE`. What's more, since then on, every time I connect the Micro bit to my computer, it enters this `MAINTENANCE` disk, no matter I press the `Reset` or not during the connection. I've tried different versions of firmwares of the Micro bit v1, but none of them succeed.

The details about this Micro bit are shown as below.

```
# DAPLink Firmware - see https://mbed.com/daplink
Unique ID: 00000000066aff565357825187123855a5a5a5a597969908
HIC ID: 97969908
Auto Reset: 0
Automation allowed: 1
Overflow detection: 0
Daplink Mode: Bootloader
Bootloader Version: 0254
Git SHA: db711ec68a861b9d9b0d7a7a82071796ec117687
Local Mods: 1
USB Interfaces: MSD
Bootloader CRC: 0x0697f838
Interface CRC: 0x4915d882
Remount count: 1
URL: https://mbed.com/daplink
```

The contents of `FAIL.TXT` are shown as below.

```
error: In application programming aborted due to an out of bounds address.
type: interface
```

So, I am wondering that, what possibly has occured this upgrade failure ? And how can I fix my Micro bit ?

Comment: I am pretty sure that the micro bit is in maintenance mode when I drag the hex file into it. And the hex file I used is exactly 0294 as you mentioned, downloaded from microbit.org. As I mentioned in the question, I've tried to drag it into micro bit many times.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that as well. But it cannot be flashed into micro bit. The micro bit keeps itself in maintanance even without holding the reset button.

Answer (score 2):

I am 7 months late, I know, and I made an account just ot answer here. I see some strange things I haven't seen before in your details;

- You're missing the part of the UID that specifies the version of the
  Micro:Bit (4 first numbers are supposed to be 9900 for 1.3 and 9901
  for 1.5, not sure if it's different if you have 1.0).
- Interface version is missing from the details.
- Local mods being set to 1 means you have unsaved local changes to the Micro:Bit.
- Remount count being set to 1 means it has failed to flash the previous hex you tried to flash to it. Not a good sign, but it means you only tried (or it only counted) once to reflash the firmware.

Try flashing an [erase hex](https://support.microbit.org/support/solutions/articles/19000053246-erase-the-program-on-the-micro-bit) to the Micro:Bit, then an [up-to-date firmware hex](https://tech.microbit.org/software/daplink-interface/#daplink-software), and lastly the [OOB hex](https://microbit.org/get-started/user-guide/out-of-box-experience/). This worked for me when I experienced a similar issue.

I hope any of this can help you, or any others that stumble upon this post in the future.

Please reach out if you still need help!

Answer (score 0):

This micro:bit has wrong HIC ID (97969908 instead of 97969901). It doesn't have original bootloader that's why you are not able to flash original interface firmware. According to DAPLink 97969908 is STM32F103XB bootloader. I think there are 2 possible solutions: 1st is to flash original bootloader and original interface firmware then, 2nd is to make some with DAPLink source files to compile a new interface firmware that would work with 97969908 bootloader.
See here https://github.com/ARMmbed/DAPLink/discussions/956